# How to trace builtin functions in python

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I am trying to understand how `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods are called in file context manager.

```
with open("test.txt") as fp:
  fp.read()
```

I have tried `step` command in pdb - instead of going to definition of the function `open`, it just executes it and moves on to the next line.

I tried using `sys.settrace()` too, but even it is not capturing the function calls `open`, `__enter__`, and `__exit__` in any of the events.

Of course, this works for functions imported from other modules and in the same module. I was assuming this should work for these builtin functions out of the box in a similar manner. I could not find any documentation pointing to this. Is it possible to step into or trace execution of builtin functions?

Using Python 2.7.

Comment: What do you mean *"how [the] methods are called"*? I'd guess that you're hitting the C implementation, which the Python debugger can't help you with.

Comment: @jonrsharpe:  I'm looking at the 3.6 CPython source code and find that the context manager code for `IOBase` is in `Lib/_pyio.py`.  Only some of the functionality is in `Objects/fileobject.c`.  Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: No, I see it [there](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/_pyio.py#l450) too, and that's what `open` returns. Is it 3.6 you're debugging in?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Ok, that means I can't step into the implementation in pdb. But still, settrace() should still return `c_call` events for the function calls.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [sys.setprofile](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile) instead of [sys.settrace](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) when tracing builtin functions:

> The system’s profile function is called similarly to the system’s trace function (see settrace()), but it is called with different events, for example it isn’t called for each executed line of code (only on call and return, but the return event is reported even when an exception has been set)

Besides the events "call" and "return", `setprofile` also offers "c_call" and "c_return" which refer to calling and returning from a builtin function.

Be aware of the altered meaning of the other two arguments `frame` and `arg`:
If `event` equals "c_call" or "c_return", `frame` is the outer frame from where the builtin function was called, so `frame.f_code.co_name` will not be the name of the builtin function but the name of the python function calling it.
Instead, `arg` is the C function object, not the return value.

So to answer your question:

> Is it possible to step into or trace execution of builtin functions?

Yes, it is possible to trace the call/return of builtin functions, however, you are not able to step into one. I guess the reason why you don't even see the c_call/c_return with your debugger is because it uses settrace and not setprofile.