# Is it possible to trace non-assigned values?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to trace the execution of a test file and need all values of comparisons and variables. The tracing of variable values is working but values that are being compared without assigning them aren't.

For example:

```
def test_random_test():
    assert random.randint(0, 10) >= 8
```

If the assertion passes, I get no information about the value generated by the random function. I know Pytest supports an experimental version but I aim to not use their API.

So, is it possible to get(trace) the generated value from the random function?

Comment: Having a random value in tests is generally an anti-pattern. Tests should behave the same way however many times you run them.
But answering your question, just assign it to a variable and test it instead.

Comment: The purpose is for detecting flakiness caused by randomness through a tracing approach which is why this is relevant for me. This extends to the fact that it will be used for tests not written by me and I will be unable to edit any test code.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61060850/1959808

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61067303/1959808

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using `sys.settrace` to trace Python functions

The function [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) could be used for finding out what values are returned by functions, as follows:

```py
"""How to trace values returned by functions, even if unassigned.

For more details:
    https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace
"""
import random
import sys


def test_random_test():
    """Sample function to trace."""
    assert random.randint(0, 10) >= 8


def tracer(frame, event, arg):
    """System's trace function."""
    if event == 'call':
        return trace_returns


def trace_returns(frame, event, arg):
    """Intercept and print values returned by functions.

    Trace function for local scopes.
    """
    co = frame.f_code
    func_name = co.co_name
    if event == 'return':
        print(f'function `{func_name}` returns: {arg}')
    # A local trace function returns the function to
    # be called the next time a trace event is
    # generated in the same local scope,
    # or `None` to turn off further tracing in
    # that scope.
    return trace_returns


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.settrace(tracer)
    test_random_test()
```

The above code outputs (in one of the runs where the assertion passes) the following (the printed integer value can vary from call to call):

```
function `_randbelow_with_getrandbits` returns: 9
function `randrange` returns: 9
function `randint` returns: 9
function `test_random_test` returns: None
```

More [examples](https://pymotw.com/3/sys/tracing.html). It is worth noting that how trace functions need to behave with `sys.settrace` has changed from Python 2 to Python 3. Points to highlight from the documentation:

> The trace function is invoked (with *event* set to `'call'`) whenever a new local scope is entered; it should return a reference to a local trace function to be used for the new scope, or `None` if the scope shouldn’t be traced.
>
> The local trace function should return a reference to itself (or to another function for further tracing in that scope), or `None` to turn off tracing in that scope.

Also, there is a package [`function_trace`](https://pypi.org/project/function_trace) that [works using `sys.settrace`](https://github.com/RedHatQE/function_trace/blob/390038c4010661471f77f238e10784f2c0502c42/function_trace/__init__.py#L346). By the way, there is also a module [`trace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html) in Python's standard library.

### Using `sys.setprofile` to trace also C functions

The above `sys.settrace`-based approach does not trace C functions. The *names* of these can be traced using the function [`sys.setprofile`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile), as follows:

```py
"""How to trace the names of C functions, including builtins.

For more details:
    https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/sys.html#sys.setprofile
"""
import random
import sys


def test_random_test():
    """Sample function to trace."""
    assert random.randint(0, 10) >= 8


def profiler(frame, event, arg):
    """Intercept also builtins."""
    co = frame.f_code
    func_name = co.co_name
    if event == 'return':
        print(f'function `{func_name}` returns: {arg}')
    elif event == 'c_return':
        # note the difference in the meaning of `func_name`:
        # it is the caller's name, not the callee's
        # (i.e., the name of the function from where the
        # C function was called, not the name of the C
        # function itself).
        # Also, we do not get the value returned by
        # the C function
        print(
            f'C function `{arg}` returns to '
            f'function `{func_name}`')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.setprofile(profiler)
    test_random_test()
```

The above code outputs in a run in which the assertion passes the following:

```
C function `<built-in method bit_length of int object at 0x10e12ba70>` returns to function `_randbelow_with_getrandbits`
C function `<built-in method getrandbits of Random object at 0x7fe91404de10>` returns to function `_randbelow_with_getrandbits`
function `_randbelow_with_getrandbits` returns: 9
function `randrange` returns: 9
function `randint` returns: 9
function `test_random_test` returns: None
function `<module>` returns: None
```

### About tracing literals

The above approaches do not print the value of the literal `8`. Based on the question, this is not necessarily a requirement from tracing, because `8` is a known value, not decided at runtime. Besides, the literal `8` does not appear to give rise to any traceable function or method event, as observed by reading the [bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytecode) of the function `test_random_test`:

```py
"""How to print a function's bytecode.

For more details:
    https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html
"""
import dis
import random


def test_random_test():
    """Sample function to trace."""
    assert random.randint(0, 10) >= 8


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dis.dis(test_random_test)
```

The above code prints:

```
 12           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (random)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              1 (randint)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (10)
              8 CALL_METHOD              2
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 (8)
             12 COMPARE_OP               5 (>=)
             14 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        20
             16 LOAD_ASSERTION_ERROR
             18 RAISE_VARARGS            1
        >>   20 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

From this we learn that the integer 8 is directly loaded as a constant:

```
10 LOAD_CONST               3 (8)
```

So tracing *every* unassigned value seems to require tracing of bytecode ([example for Python 2](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/bytecode_tracer)). However, I am not sure how readable the results of tracing at the bytecode level would be (e.g., consider the intermediate values that are created when evaluating an expression with several operators).

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer will help me forward.